# How to find the number of layers from the saved h5 file of pre-trained model?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py, pre-trained-model, transfer-learning

I have VGG-16 weights saved in h5 format. I want to see the number of layers in the network. How can I do that?

I tried using:

```
file = h5py.File(vgg16.h5)
```

after that, I checked for `file.attrs` but after this point I don't know which command to use to find the number of layers in the network.

Comment: While we can describe the general layout of the file (groups, datasets, attributes), we can't describe this specific file.  That depends entirely on how it was written.

Comment: Don't you have some sort of documentation?

Comment: Hi hpaulj ,
yes just want to know within this attributes can i see the number of layers or any option ?

Comment: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/attr.html

Comment: When you say "number of layers" are you referring to the number of datasets, or the size and shape of 1 dataset? To get dataset info, use `.shape` and `.dtype` (like numpy nomeclature). If you want the number of datasets in a group, use `len()` function on the group. An easy way to view the h5 file's data structure and contents is **HDFView** from **HDF Group**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type this code in spyder provided, you have installed Keras library. You will get all the layers in h5.file

```
from keras.models import load_model

classifier=load_model('my_model.h5')

classifier.summary()
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you have only weights and not the model structure, you can use keys() method to get all the layers name in that weight file.

For example: I have one weight file: `saved-weight.h5`

If I want to know what are the layers present in this weight file, you can do the following:

```
import h5py
file = h5py.File('saved-weight.h5')

layer_names = file.keys()

# output 
layer_names =  <KeysViewHDF5 ['add', 'bn_3', 'bn_5', 'bn_7', 
    'concatenate', 'conv_1', 'conv_2', 'conv_3',
    'dropout', 'fc_8', 'fc_9', 
    'gru_10', 'gru_10_back', 'gru_11', 'gru_11_back', 
    'input_1', 'input_3', 'input_4', 'labels', 
    'lambda', 'lambda_1', 'lambda_2', 'lambda_3', 
    'maxpool_3', 'maxpool_5', 'model', 'permute', 'reshape']>
```

These are the layers present in the saved-weights file

Comment: I think this is the proper answer for weight's only saved model

Answer (score 0):

Without your data or code, it is hard to provide more details.
To demonstrate h5py methods to access h5 data, here is a simple example that creates a h5 file with 1 group with 3 datasets. After the group and datasets are created, there is a loop to print the dataset name, shape and dtype.

```
import h5py, numpy as np
h5f=h5py.File('SO_54511719.h5','w')

ds_data = np.random.random(100).reshape(10,10)
group1 = h5f.create_group('group1')
group1.create_dataset('ds_1', data=ds_data)
group1.create_dataset('ds_2', data=ds_data)
group1.create_dataset('ds_3', data=ds_data)

print ('number of datasets in group:', len(group1))
for (dsname, dsvalue) in group1.items() :
    print ('for',dsname,':')
    print ('shape:',dsvalue.shape)
    print ('dtype:',dsvalue.dtype)

h5f.close()
```

Output looks like this:

```
number of datasets in group: 3
for ds_1 :
shape: (10, 10)
dtype: float64
for ds_2 :
shape: (10, 10)
dtype: float64
for ds_3 :
shape: (10, 10)
dtype: float64
```